# Potential memory leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, ios4

I work on a project on iPhone iOS with Xcode 4.

With Xcode > Product >Analyze I get 35 issues, all of this type:

```
 myTextField.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"0.2f", abc];
```

and the problem is "Potential leak of an object allocated at ..."

What is the offending object and how can I release it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're leaking the string that you're assigning to myTextField.text. When this assignment happens, a copy is being made (look at the property definition in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/text)). In most cases, when values are immutable, as is the case with NSStrings, a copy will give you an instance that points to the same location as the object that is being copied, with the retain count incremented by 1.

In the case of your code:

```
myTextField.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"0.2f", abc];
```

The retain count of the string that you've allocated is 2.

You will either need to (1) release, (or autorelease) the string, or (2) use one of the NSString convenience methods, e.g. stringWithFormat: to create the string. This will give you an autoreleased string so you won't have to worry about explicitly releasing it.

(1)

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"0.2f", abc];
myTextField.text = str;
[str release]
```

or

```
myTextField.text = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"0.2f", abc] autorelease];
```

(2)

```
myTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0.2f", abc]; // autoreleased
```

Comment: @iOk because NSString is immutable copy returns the same instance not a different one.

Comment: @Oscar Gomez - You're right. I've updated my answer. I also up-voted yours.

Answer (score 4):

You are responsible for releasing string object you create here - as you use alloc/init for that.

The most convenient way here to set a string is to use class method `+stringWithFormat` that returns autoreleased string - so system will release that string object for you later:

```
myTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0.2f", abc];
```

Or you can write autorelease explicitly if you want:

```
myTextField.text = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"0.2f", abc] autorelease];
```

If you don't want to use autorelease you can use temporary variable to create new string and release it after it was set for text field:

```
NSString *tempString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"0.2f", abc];
myTextField.text = tempString;
[tempString release];
```

Comment: Yes, I am responsible, but how can I release what object?

Comment: Perhaps [myTextField release]? But myTextField is a ivar.

Comment: If you use autorelease (either implicitly with +stringWithFormat: method or explicitly) then system will release object for you in some moment in future - so you don't have to worry about that. If you want to release object manually then you'll need temp variable for that

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that UiTextFields's text property is declared as:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *text
```

Therefore in this line:

```
 myTextField.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"0.2f", abc];
```

A new `NSString` is created with a retain count of 1, and then `myTextField.text` copies this object and increased its retain count by 1 or does it??, lets see what is happening:

1. A `NSString` object created with alloc initWithFormat with a retain count of 1
2. A `NSString` object with is a copy of the previous String, but because ***`NStrings` are immutable in this case, copy returns the same object!***, therefore the `NSString` actually has a retain count of 2.